# Can anyone help me how to migrate an SVN branch to Git repository?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

The

```
git svn clone SVN:URL ...
```

command would clone the entire repository while I want to use only one specific branch of the repository and not the complete SVN repository.

Answer (score 0):

Read, understand [git-svn Man Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) and use after it

`git svn clone URL/OF/BRANCH`

(see first sample from "BASIC EXAMPLES" section)